# mvn clean package error, Connection reset on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to resolve dependency of my application using `mvn clean package` and `mvn clean install` but I am facing connection reset error.

I dockerized the app, and it's working fine using docker and building without error, but when it comes to ubuntu, it doesn't want to build.

Previously I was using VM to run ubuntu and it was working fine too.

maven package I need to receive is `org.glassfish:javax.el-impl:jar:3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1`, I tried to acces it through maven reposity on web browser and I was getting Connection Reset there too.

My Application is not directly depending on this package, dependency map is as following
`io.thorntail:jaxrs:jar:2.3.0.Final -> io.thorntail:undertow:jar:2.3.0.Final -> io.thorntail:ee:jar:2.3.0.Final -> org.glassfish:javax.el-impl:jar:3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1`

I tried everything but no sign of success.
Weird part is that it's working on docker, and it's been working on windows with VM. it suddenly stopped working on ubuntu. I would appreciate any help.

Here are some extra information
OS : Ubuntu 20.04
mvn --version:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T18:06:16+03:00)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.6.2
Java version: 1.8.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /opt/jdk/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.8.0-55-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< *app* >-----------------
[INFO] Building WildFly Quickstarts: *app* 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
Downloading from jboss-public-repository-group: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/glassfish/javax.el-impl/3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1/javax.el-impl-3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.667 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-13T20:50:18+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project *app*: Could not resolve dependencies for project *package*:*app*:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at io.thorntail:jaxrs:jar:2.3.0.Final -> io.thorntail:undertow:jar:2.3.0.Final -> io.thorntail:ee:jar:2.3.0.Final -> org.glassfish:javax.el-impl:jar:3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.glassfish:javax.el-impl:jar:3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish:javax.el-impl:pom:3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1 from/to jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: What about showing the real error message you got?

Comment: @khmarbaise edited, included the error.

Comment: @RezaMotlagh are you using any Proxy? or your internet connection is fine i.e you able to access the internet through IDE?

Comment: @MohitSharma system is clean, no proxy, and yes I can, it actually resolving dependencies for fine but on this one it gets stuck and shows the above error.

Comment: It looks like the given repository does not exist anymore ... can you say where you have configured that repository to be used?

Comment: @khmarbaise it actually exists and im using it on my ubuntu vm on windows and its working perfectly, i didn't use it directly as mentioned in the problem description.

Comment: The output `Downloading from jboss-public-repos` shows it tries to contact it but it does not finished the download which means either the repo is not accessible via Maven or the artifact does not exist in that repo...

Comment: yes I noticed it, I think it might be proxy issue with ubuntu which I still don't know where it's setup. Have to go deeper a bit to find out the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus is offline, and I don't know if these artifacts are available somewhere else.
If not, you need to find a replacement for `javax.el-impl-3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Jboss repository is unreachable. I got the same issue and managed to fix it by this workaround:

1. Specify an alternative repository URL in your maven configuration. For example I have this:

   ```xml
   <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

     <pluginGroups>
       <pluginGroup>org.jenkins-ci.tools</pluginGroup>
     </pluginGroups>

     <profiles>
       <profile>
         <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
         <repositories>
           <repository>
             <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
             <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
             <url>https://www.aht-group.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
             <layout>default</layout>
             <releases>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
               <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
             </releases>
             <snapshots>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
               <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
             </snapshots>
           </repository>
         </repositories>
         <pluginRepositories>
           <pluginRepository>
             <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
             <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
             <url>https://www.aht-group.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
             <layout>default</layout>
             <releases>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
               <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
             </releases>
             <snapshots>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
               <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
             </snapshots>
           </pluginRepository>
         </pluginRepositories>
       </profile>
     </profiles>

     <activeProfiles>
       <activeProfile>jboss-public-repository</activeProfile>
     </activeProfiles>

   </settings>
   ```
2. Try `mvn` command again with `-s <path/to/maven-settings.xml>` to apply the specified repository URL.

> Note: I used `https://www.aht-group.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/` as an alternative because it contains all the necessary packages in my project. You may need to find another repository URL if this one does not have what you need.